# How to make a GRUB2 Floppy?

Tags: grub

I want to make a GRUB2 floppy disk with an ext2 filesystem that I can use to load something on the disk via multiboot. I'm working on debian unstable, and I don't think it has legacy GRUB on it atm so I was trying to work out ways of going with grub2 instead of legacy grub.
The complicated part is that I don't actually have a floppy drive atm- I'm trying to make a floppy disk image. grub-install doesn't seem to like installing to /dev/loop0 (complains about "no such disk"). I'm really at my wit's end trying to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

To [install GRUB on a floppy](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_3.html) you just need to copy the stage1 and stage2 to the first sectors of the disk.

Comment: The link is for GRUB legacy not GRUB2 like the QO asked for...